# Intellij does not update CSS with LessCSS Maven plugin

Tags: css, maven, intellij-idea, ide, less

I am currently using lesscss-maven-plugin by org.lesscss in my Intellij Spring application; the build is ok, and it is compiling properly.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
            <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/less</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/css</outputDirectory>
                <compress>true</compress>
                    <includes>
                         <include>bootstrap/bootstrap.less</include>
                         <include>template.less</include>
                         <include>var.less</include>
                     </includes>
                     <force>true</force>
                <lessJs>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/js/less-rhino-1.7.0.js</lessJs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

To update the css output directory, I have to run a `mvn clean install` and relaunch my tomcat... This is definitely not efficient !!

This method works perfectly under Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Maven Projects" tab, go to the project and look under "Plugins" for the lesscss plugin. Set it to Execute before/after your desired step and you should be golden.

[image: plugin configuration]

A more elegant and global setting would be cool, though. Anyone else have a hint?